# amplify codegen ENOENT: no such file or directory, open scheme.graphql

Tags: javascript, amazon-web-services, graphql, aws-amplify

I am creating my schemas for GraphQL as suggested in `amplify-cli` after doing `amplify api gql-compile` here:

```
GraphQL schema compiled successfully.

Edit your schema at /var/www/unsal.co.uk/amplify/backend/api/unsalcouk/schema.graphql or place .graphql files in a directory at /var/www/unsal.co.uk/amplify/backend/api/unsalcouk/schema
```

So my folder structure is as follows:

```
/var/www/unsal.co.uk/amplify/backend/api/unsalcouk/schema
   ¬ /var/www/unsal.co.uk/amplify/backend/api/unsalcouk/schema/division.graphql
   ¬ /var/www/unsal.co.uk/amplify/backend/api/unsalcouk/schema/index.graphql
```

But when doing a codegen I get the following error:

```
hutber@hutber:/var/www/unsal.co.uk$ amplify codegen
ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/var/www/unsal.co.uk/amplify/backend/api/littlewishlist/build/schema.graphql
```

Where can I put my .graphql files to have them picked up by codegen?

Comment: Happened to me too. For some reason it adds the `build` directory to the path. Did you figure it our?

Answer (score 3):

https://github.com/aws-amplify/amplify-codegen/issues/311#issuecomment-978026336

removing old graphql api by using `amplify remove codegen` then select the old one (amplify doesn't support multiple Graphql as of the moment)

Answer (score 2):

Running `amplify pull` and then re-running `amplify codegen` did the job for me

Comment: I've got the same error and a previous pull didn't help me, unfortunately.

Answer (score 0):

Nothing but **changing the region** helped me after spending hours.